# setting up a counter in a R simulation

Tags: r, simulation

I would like to do a simulation in R.  I would like to set up a loop using some large number of trials.  Specifically I would like to use a normal distribution with known mean, Standard deviation and N = 9.  I would like to set up a counter which counts the number of times on of the replicates goes below (or above) a certain value.  Also I would like to see a histogram of the data  generated.

Comment: What did you try yourself ?

Comment: This type of very simple Monte Carlo may be easier to approach *not* with a loop structure.

Comment: I am a beginner and couldnt figure out how to use the counter

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of loops, so I'd do something like this:

```
func<-function(n){
  counter=0
  x<-rnorm(1,0,1)
  if(x>2|x<(-2)) counter<-1
  return(c(n,x,counter))
}
n=1:1000
sum(do.call(rbind,lapply(n,func))[,3])



> sum(do.call(rbind,lapply(n,func))[,3])
[1] 41
> sum(do.call(rbind,lapply(n,func))[,3])
[1] 43
> sum(do.call(rbind,lapply(n,func))[,3])
[1] 43
> sum(do.call(rbind,lapply(n,func))[,3])
[1] 39
```

while the `do.call(rbind,lapply(n,func))` will provide you with the actual data you need to make the histogram of the numbers created:

```
dat<-data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(n,func)))
names(dat)<-c("n","x","counter")
head(dat)
  n          x counter
1 1 -0.6591145       0
2 2  1.8163984       0
3 3 -2.0291848       1
4 4  0.3309398       0
5 5 -0.8214298       0
6 6  0.5275238       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines.

```
#in this structure each row in the matrix is a sim rep
sim.data<- matrix(rnorm(9*1000,0,1),1000,9)

#this counts number of observations below threshold for each rep
below <- apply(sim.data, 1, function(x) sum(x<0.60))

hist(below)
```